# Mounting a Canon EF lens on a Leica M body?

Tags: canon, adapter, lens-mount, rangefinder, leica

Is it possible to use existing Canon EF lenses with a Leica body with an M mount?

I've seen various discussions in the Internet on this combination, but usually the other way round (mounting a Leica lens on a Canon SLR body).

Answer (score 7):

Is it possible? Yes. Will you be able to focus it... not really. You won't be able to step it down either. Really... this is probably the worst technically possible combo I can think of.

Comment: Agreed. Get a manual focus lens with an adapter ring if you must have a SLR lens on a Leica M.

Answer (score 5):

[This site](http://www.graphics.cornell.edu/~westin/misc/mounts-by-register.html) lists the flange distances for most lenses.  Any lens system that has a flange distance greater than yours should be able to be adapted without extra glass.

You can see that the Leica M mount is only 27.95mm and should be able to adapt almost any glass given the proper adapter.  If that adapter exists, I can't say.